# JQuery on Click event function call

Tags: jquery

I would like to call a function from the jQuery Click event.
I tried the annotation below which doesn't work.

```
$(".menu_link").click(GetContentAndSlide());
```

What is the right annotation?

Comment: try `$(".menu_link").click(GetContentAndSlide);`

Comment: @clyde-lobo It is legal to post a solution as a answer.

Comment: @"The Scrum Meister" : yup i know that... just posted it in a hurry.By the time i realized it.you had already answered it ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$(".menu_link").click(GetContentAndSlide);
```

remove the `()`, you are executing the function, instead of passing the function reference.

Another option would be (in case your function uses the `this` pointer) to wrap it around with a anonymous function:

```
$(".menu_link").click(function() {GetContentAndSlide()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, .click didn't work for me.

What worked was

```
$(".menu_link").on('click', GetContentAndSlide);
```